# Use Taxonomy ACF to affect Custom Taxonomy post count

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, custom-taxonomy

Is there a way to use an "ACF Taxonomy Field" to affect "Custom Taxonomy" post count? Right now I am using ACF Taxonomy Field, but my Custom Taxonomies have 0 posts assigned.

I want to use ACF to assign Custom Post to Custom Taxonomy:
[image]

Instead of the default way:
[image]

Is this possible? I'm trying to do this way because it is more friendly to the end-user and ACF is more flexible; I can restrict it if I need the user to select *only* one taxonomy and make other restrictions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Very big and basic mistake... Taxonomy ACF has a checkbox:
[image]

Thats make the Taxonomy ACF affect the Custom Taxonomy post count.